# Vulkan: Using buffer aliasing to implement a defragmentation scheme

Tags: vulkan

Say I have one `VkBuffer` bound to every device allocation, and use appropriate combinations of `vkCmdCopyBuffer` to perform defragmentation of an arena block-by-block.

Say an arena may contain linear and non-linear data in any appropriately-aligned arrangement. Due to the immutability of `VkImage` after binding, defragmentation will involve constructing and binding new `VkImage`s at the new locations of image data that have been moved.

None of the resources within an arena undergoing defragmentation are bound to anything, or could be considered "in-use".

This isn't difficult to implement, though I have a concern:

Is it UB to use `vkCmdCopyBuffer` to move an image's data (as to avoid redundant layout transitions), then construct a new `VkImage` at the new location?

My thoughts are that perhaps an implementation would do something strange, like rely on absolute device addresses within some internal bookkeeping structure, making it UB to treat image data as POD until bound to a new object.

Comment: Your last paragraph describes the problem. "Image Layout" covers things like lossless compression. Compression often involved metadata separate from pixel data which tells how to interpret the bytes stored in the "pixel" memory. On some implementations, this metadata is part of the VkImage memory but addressed in a non-position-independent way. In others, it might be stored elsewhere and addressed by the physical address of the pixel data. There are other snags, like swizzling layouts that are sensitive to physical alignment to achieve good distribution over memory channels / banks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's look at this systematically.

So you find a suitable destination area for your image. You do a `vkCmdCopyBuffer` to copy from the source area to the destination area. Now you create a new `VkImage` for that destination area, and the initial layout you specify is... what?

See, there are only two valid `initialLayout` values in `VkCreateImageInfo`: undefined or preinitialized. And preinitialized is only works for images that use linear tiling, since there is no well-defined layout for optimal tiled images.

So you can't use preinitialized layout. And using undefined layout means that the next image transition you use will potentially mangle whatever data is there. Now, undefined layout *might work* on some implementations. On implementations that don't care about layout, it might work. It also might work on implementations if the source image was in the general layout.

But none of that is *guaranteed* to work by the standard. As far as the standard is concerned, if you set the layout to be undefined, then the data will not be preserved. So regardless of questions of buffer/image aliasing, this can't work.

You have to create the `VkImage` at the destination, then use `vkCmdCopyImage` to copy from the source image to the destination.

It should also be noted that, even if the layout issue worked, the [aliasing rules](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#resources-memory-aliasing) tell us that copying from non-host-accessible memory (ie: images in optimal tiling or non-general/preinitialized layout) to host-accessible memory yields undefined values. So even if the layout issue weren't a problem, the copy itself doesn't work. In theory, at least.

Comment: I'm tracking image layouts manually. I'd provide the last known layout (or 'undefined'), as the data wasn't altered, just "teleported". Since I have to provide the known layout for every barrier, I have little reason to believe the driver is doing the same (TBH, a sorely irritating facet of this API). Unless vkBindImageMemory does more than just associate a `VkImage` with some memory (possibly clobbering some metadata), I can think there would only be an issue with the an internal tree or linked list...

Comment: @defube: It doesn't matter. You cannot provide the "last known layout" because Vulkan *does not let you*. `initialLayout` can only be preinitialized or undefined. And if you transition from undefined to the last known layout, the standard makes no guarantees about the content of that memory. And therefore, you would be relying on undefined behavior. And really, since you're going to have to create the destination `VkImage` *anyway*, what is so bad about just doing an image copy? Is it having to do multiple transfers?

Comment: @defube: BTW, I added an [issue on this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/509) to the official Vulkan repository. You may want to keep tabs on it, to see what they say about supporting such a thing.

Comment: The issue is needing scratch space and having to do multiple layout transitions. Defragmentation may place an image into a lower address that still overlaps its old location, and a buffer copy is the only other way the contents could be preserved without a staging area. So, it looks like being portable means needing scratch space for defrag (not like it happens all that frequently anyway). I was hoping that `UNDEFINED` image layout would just mean "don't touch it", then I would transition away from the last known layout, etc...

Comment: One possibility for the implementation is that each vkImage can have a different optimal tiling format for *reasons*.